# execl() arguments

Tags: command-line, c

How can I use execl() function with arguments which are entered by an user in C?

I can do it with `execv(args[0],args)`. How can I convert execv() to execl() ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`execv` and `execl` do exactly the same thing, with the difference that `execl` is intended for use when you know in advance the number of command-line arguments while `execv` allows the number of arguments to be dynamically determined.

The more general function is `execv`; `execl` is a sort of shorthand when the number of arguments is known and allows the programmer to avoid constructing the `argv[]` array.

Anyway, to answer the question as asked: you must know in advance the *maximum* number of arguments that will be passed to the program to be `exec`d. If you know the maximum number of arguments then you can prepare in advance a call to `execl` unwinding the argument array.

Suppose you have:

```
char * exec_argv [21];
char * exec_pathname;
```

The following two calls are equivalent for any legal contents of the argument array `exec_argv[]`:

```
execv (exec_pathname, exec_argv);

execl (exec_pathname, 
  exec_argv [0], exec_argv [1], exec_argv [2], exec_argv [3],
  exec_argv [4], exec_argv [5], exec_argv [6], exec_argv [7],
  exec_argv [8], exec_argv [9], exec_argv [10], exec_argv [11], 
  exec_argv [12], exec_argv [13], exec_argv [14], exec_argv [15],
  exec_argv [16], exec_argv [17], exec_argv [18], exec_argv [19],
  NULL
);
```

(The last argument of `execl` is `NULL` instead of `exec_argv[20]` because `gcc` will look for it if invoked with `-Wall`; since there *must* be a `NULL` somewhere in `exec_args[]` this does not introduce any difference in the effects of the two function calls.)